# Ember: How do I add a file into the treeForAddon after postBuild?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a case where I am using node-sass functions to generate a JS file after sass has completed compiling. I am outputting the file into the addon/utils directory; however, the file is not being picked until the project is built the second time.

I feel this would easily be solved if I ran SASS first and then compile the JS next (after trees have been updated with the new JS file), but I can't find anything that does that.

Any suggestions on how I could make this work?